# ExtJS ComboBox - displaying "Any" in the the field when All Items are selected

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, selection, extjs4.1

I do have a ComboBox component in ExtJS which I am using as a filter.

User can select multiple items (multiSelect : true). When the values are selected, they are correctly shown in the field. When no item is selected, the value from *emptyText* property is shown.

Now, is there a simple way how to define the text for the case when all the options are selected? Something like *allSelectedText*?

This is a simple definition of ComboBox:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    multiSelect: true,
    fieldLabel: "Select item",
    emptyText: "Please select",
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
        data: [
            {"id": "1","name": "Item 1"}, 
            {"id": "2","name": "Item 2"},
            {"id": "3","name": "Item 3"}
        ]}),
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
});
```

This is how it looks now:

[image: Current]

This is what I would like to see:

[image]

I have managed to interact with the label (next to the field) but I can't find easy way how to change the contents of the input element.

Here is the jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/84dj8/

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending ages on this - here is a simple solution

```
Ext.define('AnySelectedCombo', {
   extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
   alias: 'widget.anyselectedcombo',
   cls: "cst-filter",
   allSelectedText: "All", // default

   getDisplayValue : function() {
      // Check if all items are selected
      if (this.getStore() && this.value && (this.value.length > 0) && (this.getStore().getCount() == this.value.length)) {
        return this.allSelectedText;
      }
      // Otherwise return as normally
      return this.callParent(arguments);
   }
});
```

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/84dj8/9/

Answer (score 0):

There are no easy way to do this, but it's possible to create small workaround:

```
listeners: {
    'select': function(cmp, rec){
        var store = cmp.getStore(),
            values = cmp.getValue();

        if(store.getCount() == values.length) {
            cmp.setValue('All');                  
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/84dj8/1/

Comment: Thanks very much Pavel. It however changes the value of the field which results in firing other events, such as change. Also, the items in the dropdown are unselected right after you select the last item.

Comment: You are welcome. It's true, that this operation fires additional event. Probably it's possible to create workaround with using [link](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-resumeEvents)suspendEvent/resumeEvent functions.

Comment: Sorry, sent previous message by mistake. Probably changeEvent will not be fired if setValue function will be written between suspendEvent and resumeEvent. And for the selection problem you need to manually go through all values in the list and add 'selected' class to each element.